# Move an example within one draft

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-examples

I just want to move an example above another example.
The whole draft is created by me and currently not public.
Isn't that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reorder examples. They are ordered by votes. Instead, make sure that the examples can be in any order.

You can, however, click the pin icon to “pin” an example to the top.

Comment: Oh, I absolutely forgot about the sorting by votes.. Thank you!